# Double.longBitsToDouble and Double.doubleToRawLongBits with NaN

Tags: java

Why is

```
Double.NaN != Double.longBitsToDouble(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(Double.NaN));
```

although the [SE 6 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits%28double%29) says the following:

> In all cases, the result is a `long` integer that, when given to the
>   `longBitsToDouble(long)` method, will produce a floating-point value the same as the
>   argument to `doubleToRawLongBits`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But `Double.NaN != Double.NaN`...

Comment: Also, there are something like 2^52 - 2 different NaN's (at the bit level), as you'll see if you read the Javadocs.  But even two NaNs with the same bit pattern will be `!=`.